# How to get the type of variable in the declaration ANTLR

Tags: antlr4

I am developing a DSL with ANTLR and in the assignment rule I want to know the type of variable here is my grammar.

```
assign: name = ID '=' value = ( INT  |STRING | DATE )
            {
                // get type here
                parameters.add(new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry($name.text, $value.text));
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not litter your grammar with code, but rather do this inside a listener:

```java
@Override
public void enterAssign(StudyParserParser.AssignContext ctx) {

    String id = ctx.name.getText();
    String value = ctx.value.getText();

    switch (ctx.value.getType()) {
        case StudyParserLexer.INT:
            System.out.println(id + " is an INT: " + value);
            break;
        case StudyParserLexer.STRING:
            System.out.println(id + " is a STRING: " + value);
            break;
        case StudyParserLexer.DATE:
            System.out.println(id + " is a DATE: " + value);
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown type: " + ctx.value.getType() + ", value: " + value);
    }
}
```